# How to make Excel "IF" formula calculate blank cells as "0"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I make the IF function consider blank cells as "0".

Here is the formula I am using in the H column cells: IF(E1>F1,"YES","NO")

Here is the specific Example:

E      | F     |G      | H     |

10     | 0     |30     | YES   |

10     | 5     |10     | YES    |

10     |-------|-------| NO   |

H3 should return "YES" I would think.

In this scenario I cannot change the blank cells to "0", they have to remain blank.

What would be the correct formula for me to use?

I have tried searching around on google and stackoverflow, but the only things I can find are where people are trying to *NOT* have blanks be considered "0".

Comment: It handles automatically

Comment: Don't you think all the values in `Column H` should be `NO` considering you are returning `NO` if condition is `TRUE`.

Comment: If `F` is to be `0` then 10>0 which is true?!? (row1)

Comment: Your example makes no sense.  Your formula is doing what it should and is interpreting blanks as `0`.  However, it will **always** do that.  You cannot have it find the same condition and sometimes return `YES` and sometimes return `NO`.  In each of your examples, `E1` is greater than `F1`. Your formula says return a `NO`.  So all of your results in `H` should be `NO` and work that way if you try it.

Comment: Another comment: What is actually in the cells in column `F`?  Are the cells empty? Or do they contain a formula?  If they contain a formula, and are returning a null string, then you might try `=IF(N(E1)>N(F1),"No","Yes")`

Comment: As @RonRosenfeld pointed out my example made no sense. It had some mistakes in it which I've fixed. In Column F I have a vlookup from another sheet. The cell in the other sheet is actually blank with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(ISBLANK(F1),"YES",IF(E1>F1,"YES","NO"))` - Will check for a blank cell, this will work if column F is not formulated

`=IF(F1="","YES",IF(E1>F1,"YES","NO"))` - Performs a similar check but for the set value `""` which is a formulated forced blank cell

`=IF(ISNUMBER(F1),IF(E1>F1,"YES","NO"),"YES")` - Sense check for if the cell is a number (In case the formulated column is a numerical calculation)

Comment: Thank you!  The second formula you gave worked, as the blank cells are created as by a formula.

Answer (score 0):

**The excel handles automatically for blank cells .**

> If you enter text it will show error and suggest for correction.
>   the formaula i use in this examle is

```
=IF(A1>=B1,"Yes","No")
```

> The result appear as follow

[image]

Comment: @Mrig I just give an example that excel handles automatically.

Comment: Sorry but I had a mistake in the question and formula I posted.  This has been corrected.